# Why MySQL ... why?

Tags: mysql

So, with mysql, why do things that don't equal each other, equal each other?  For example, why ...

```
mysql> SELECT '3' = 3;
+---------+
| '3' = 3 |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
```

Just, why?

And more importantly ...

```
mysql> SELECT 0 = '';
+--------+
| 0 = '' |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
```

But, why?

Also ...

```
mysql> SELECT '3x' into @foo;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @foo, CAST(@foo as signed), @foo = CAST(@foo as signed);
+------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
| @foo | CAST(@foo as signed) | @foo = CAST(@foo as signed) |
+------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
| 3x   |                    3 |                           1 |
+------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Dear God, why?

But worse still ...

```
mysql> SELECT '3x', CAST('3z' as signed), '3x' = CAST('3z' as signed);
+----+----------------------+-----------------------------+
| 3x | CAST('3z' as signed) | '3x' = CAST('3z' as signed) |
+----+----------------------+-----------------------------+
| 3x |                    3 |                           1 |
+----+----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Why, oh why? Why does it make me cry so ... ?

Comment: just wait until you try javascript...

Comment: As for the why: because I think one of the most important design rules in MySQL was to avoid returning errors at any cost and try to guess what the user meant even if that might return incorrect results. But you can always upgrade to Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Do you happen to know what postgres would do in these cases?  If not, I might try it out later.  Just get some thoroughly unexpected results when trying to compare some stuff, I'm trying to validate user input as being an integer, so I thought I'd cast it, and compare to the original input, and found that they were always equal ... not handy!

Comment: Validating user input in the database seems....weird.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Is this the same design philosophy that let's you include columns in your select-list when aggregating data, even if the column is not included in the GROUP BY clause, or used in an aggregate expression? *shivers*

Comment: @Dan: that would be my assumption yes. Or the same philosophy that makes it accept e.g. the definition for foreign keys, check constraints even though they aren't really created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all there in the documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html

Especially in the line

> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

So all your comparisons are floating-point comparisons and as such make perfect sense.

One can argue wether automatic type-conversion makes sense at all (should it be possible to compare `'1'` to 1?)...

Comment: That's what one gets when trying to make sense from everything instead of throwing errors where they are due...